# How to upgrade the PHP version on macOS Mojave using Homebrew?

Tags: php, homebrew

I was reading some of the older solutions for this on Stack overflow but turns out `homebrew/php` is now deprecated so none of the previous solutions seem to be working now.

The reason why I want to update my version of PHP is because I'm trying to use the `NumberFormatter` class but it cannot be found. I can't find the `php-intl` extension on Homebrew either.

Any help with this would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I'm using Mojave and recently used the instructions [here](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-multiple-php-versions) to install multiple versions of PHP. I thought they were pretty easy to follow and everything went well.

Comment: But what about the default PHP installation that comes with the operating system? i.e. `/usr/bin/php` - any way to overwrite that after installing the new version with Homebrew?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything with it. If you install a different one with homebrew, it should effectively override the built-in version.

Answer (score -2):

*"Realistically, you can't."*

Instead, your situation is analogous to *"running <X> in a shared hosting environment,"* where you cannot change the host's environment but you *can* arrange for your software to run in an environment of your own choosing.

"The particulars of this entirely depend, of course, upon 'what is *your* exact situation,'" so I cannot meaningfully comment further, but please ... "Google it."  *(And this comment, by the way, IS NOT meant to be in any way "dismissive," as you will plainly see when you begin to explore.)*

(And then, by all means, feel free to further-describe your exact situation – once you have done so.  We're happy to help ...)

Comment: This is not a proper answer.